# Error in check disk for defects. Dual installation

Tags: dual-boot, disk-check

Without installing Ubuntu running an Ubuntu live session from a USB drive it runs smoothly, but while I install dual boot an error appears while it's looking for another operating system and when I check the disk for defects this image shows error. I tried both 18.04 and 16.04, but the same error occurs.

[image]